# Using rubocop from an environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code, rubocop

When I open the terminal before I can run any ruby commands I have to first run:

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

I have no idea what this does, but it seems to work. My problem now is that in order to run rubocop linter I also need to run that command first, the problem with that is that the extension would try and run it without that command and thus it doesn't work.

Is there some other way to permanently fix whatever issue that line is fixing in order for rubocop extension in vscode works?

Comment: is that the ruby version of virtual environment activation